# Easiest way to repeat MANY mouse clicks?

Tags: macos, automator, google-chrome, mouse

#### Problem

I imported a large OPML file to a Feedly (a RSS/source aggregator web service), and the import got messed up. I now need to delete the entries on their website using *Google Chrome*, but there is no way to bulk delete.

Instead of manually clicking almost a thousand times, I'd like to quickly automate a Left-Mouse Click and loop it for as many times.

The reason I'm stating my specific use-case is because I am unlikely to ever use this particular automation again. I need a quick and dirty solution.

---

#### Question

What is indeed the fastest and easiest way to record and repeatedly perform a mouse-automation tasks, in macOS Sierra?

---

#### Solutions

I took a stab at macOS Automator's *Watch Me Do* but really didn't get it to work with Chrome as it seems to interpret Left-Mouse clicks as *"Drag the scroll thumb in the scroll area"* (??)<sup>1</sup>.

I also investigated some third-party options like [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) and [Murgaa](http://www.murgaa.com/) (not endorsing any of these, nor have I tried them), as well as some scripting alternatives like [CliClick](https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick) but I must admit that learning how to script with these utilities feels a bit cumbersome right now.

I'm preferably looking for a reliable, and free, Mouse/Click Automator circa 2017 with a GUI. Is there something like that which is recommendable? Or should I tinker more with Automator or something else?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>I've added Automator to the macOS Accessibility settings.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know you already rejected CliClick, but what if the script was provided for you? It’s actually quite simple. In `Script Editor` enter the following:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    repeat 500 times
        do shell script "/Users/<you>/Desktop/cliclick c:" & "1694,18"
        delay 1.5
    end repeat
end tell
```

Replace `1694,18` with the actual coordinates of the button you want to click. Those can be obtained by pressing <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> and hovering your cursor over the button.

Also replace `<you>` with your account name, and adjust the `delay` as appropriate, to account for any animation or form postback.

Obviously this is all assuming the click occurs in the same spot each time. Your question doesn’t specify, although I get the sense that that is the case. Otherwise it would be very hard to script as a repeating click.

Comment: An answer very scalable to other situations : nice. got my vote.

Comment: Thanks for providing the script! Given that, this was a very reasonable solution. Just for the record: I downloaded CliClick with Homebrew, and the path to be used is probably then: `/usr/local/bin/cliclick`. As your answer suggests, this only works if the button to be pressed is at the same location. Else it would be better to use Selenium according to CSS/XPath etc (as suggested by another answer). Lastly, I think it would be in the community to add answers for a completely GUI solution, but I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: 3rd party scripts like these no longer work for security reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Selenium isn't intended for this purpose, but likely could be scripted to solve your problem.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 2):

on MacOS this worked for me:

First install cliclick:

```
brew install cliclick
```

Then run this script:

```
for i in {1..20}; do cliclick c:1410,290; sleep 1s; done
```

This will trigger a mouse click each second at coordinates 1410, 290.
The script will repeat 20 times.